# How to read JSON Response from URL and use the keys and values inside Javascript (array inside array)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

My Controller Function:

```
public function displayAction(Request $request)
{
    $stat = $this->get("app_bundle.helper.display_helper");
    $displayData = $stat->generateStat();
    return new JsonResponse($displayData);
}
```

My JSON Response from URL is:
`{"Total":[{"date":"2016-11-28","selfies":8},{"date":"2016-11-29","selfies":5}],"Shared":[{"date":"2016-11-28","shares":5},{"date":"2016-11-29","shares":2}]}`

From this Response I want to pass the values to variables (selfie,shared) in javascript file like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var selfie = [
            [(2016-11-28),8], [(2016-11-29),5]]
        ];

var shared = [
            [(2016-11-28),5], [(2016-11-29),2]]
        ];
});
```

Comment: What is the `alert` shows?

Comment: Because you use getJSON the parameter data is already a json object.

Comment: Why downvote this question ? this was my genuine problem! Since I am new to javascript. @MysterX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

First traverse the top object data and then traverse each property of the data which is an array.

```js
var data = {"total":[{"date":"2016-11-28","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-11-29","selfies":2},{"date":"2016-11-30","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-12-01","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-12-02","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-12-03","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-12-04","selfies":0}],"shared":[{"date":"2016-11-28","shares":0},{"date":"2016-11-29","shares":0},{"date":"2016-11-30","shares":0},{"date":"2016-12-01","shares":0},{"date":"2016-12-02","shares":0},{"date":"2016-12-03","shares":0},{"date":"2016-12-04","shares":0}]}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k){
  
   var val = data[k];
   
    val.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.date);
    console.log(element.selfies != undefined ? element.selfies : element.shares );
      
    });
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your callback use the following:

```
$.each(data.total, function(i, o){
    console.log(o.selfies);
    console.log(o.date);

    // or do whatever you want here
})
```

Because you make the request using jetJSON the parameter `data` sent to the callback is already an object so you don't need to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var text ='{"Total":[{"date":"2016-11-28","selfies":0},{"date":"2016-11-29","selfies":2}],"Shared":[{"date":"2016-11-28","shares":0},{"date":"2016-11-29","shares":0}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(text);

var objKeys = Object.keys(jsonObj);

for (var i in objKeys) {
   var totalSharedObj = jsonObj[objKeys[i]];
   if(objKeys[i] == 'Total') {
     for (var j in totalSharedObj) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
  "selfies on "+totalSharedObj[j].date+":"+totalSharedObj[j].selfies+"<br>";
   }
   }
   if(objKeys[i] == 'Shared') {
     for (var k in totalSharedObj) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
  "shares on "+totalSharedObj[k].date+":"+totalSharedObj[k].shares+"<br>";
   }
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of Research & took help from other users and could finally fix my problem. So thought of sharing my solution.

```
$.get( "Address for my JSON data", function( data ) {


        var selfie =[];
        $(data.Total).each(function(){
            var tmp = [
                this.date,
                this.selfies
            ];
            selfie.push(tmp);
        });
        var shared =[];
        $(data.Shared).each(function(){
            var tmp = [
                this.date,
                this.shares
            ];
            shared.push(tmp);
        });
});
```